# Append updated to table without refreshing whole table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to refresh my data without having to remove the whole table and then repopulate. Because when I'm filtering my table, it'll will refresh the table and then the filter will be reset and will have to filter table again.

I don't want to use any more plugins such as "datatables" from https://datatables.net/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Sync status list table -->
<div class="table-responsive">          
    <table class="table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
       <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>User</th>
         <th>Sync</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>

       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
// Get all sync status' logging, and append to sync logging table (sync page)
function GetSyncStatusUsers(selectFromGroup)
{
var currentArray;

$.post("php/getServerLogging.php",
{
    command: "GetLastSyncUser",
    groupName: selectFromGroup
})

.success(function (data)
{
    var jsonMessage = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#dataTables-example td').remove();
    $("#dataTables-example tr:empty").remove();

    // Check to see if response message returns back "OK"
    if (jsonMessage.RESPONSE == 'OK')
    {

        if ($("#dataTables-example").length)
        {

            var syncStatusTableBody = $('#dataTables-example').children('tbody');
            var syncStatusTable = syncStatusTableBody.length ? syncStatusTableBody : $('#dataTables-example');

            // Loop through all the returned records and add them to select box
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonMessage.RECORDS.length; i++)
            {

                var currentRecord = jsonMessage.RECORDS[i];

                // Returned from mysql timestamp/datetime field
                var LastSyncTime;
                if (currentRecord['LastSync'] == null)
                {
                    LastSyncTime = "No Last sync record found";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Return last sync time in UK format
                    LastSyncTime =   GetCurrentDateUKFormatFromSQL(currentRecord['LastSync']['date']);
                }

                // Append to sync status table
                syncStatusTable.append("<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord['Firstname'] + ' ' + currentRecord['Surname'] + "</td><td>" + LastSyncTime + " (" + TimeAgo(SubtractDates(currentRecord['LastSync']['date'])) + ")" + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    }
});
}


function GetCurrentDateUKFormatFromSQL(dateFromSQL)
{

     // Format last SQL time to UK format
     var dateStr = dateFromSQL;
     var a = dateStr.split(" ");
     var logDate = a[0].split("-");
     var logTime = a[1].split(":");
     var dateHours = parseInt(logTime[0]);
     var dateMinutes = parseInt(logTime[1]);
     var dateSeconds = parseInt(logTime[2]);

     if (dateSeconds < 10)
     {
        dateSeconds = "0" + dateSeconds; 
     }

     if (dateMinutes < 10)
     {
        dateMinutes = "0" + dateMinutes;
     }

     if (dateHours < 10)
     {
        dateHours = "0" + dateHours;
     }

     // Return UK formatted date
     var ukFormateSQLDate = logDate[2] + '-' + logDate[1] + '-' + logDate[0] + ' ' + dateHours + ':' + dateMinutes + ':' + dateSeconds;
     return ukFormateSQLDate;
}
```

Comment: There a nice demo here for filtering a table http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL

Comment: @Tasos Please read my question carefully, I know how to filter my table. My question is about refreshing data and not having the filter cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and trying new things, I finally found the solution I was looking for. So here is the answer if anybody is looking for similar solution or have been trying to work out how to do this.

**Previous code:**

```
// Get all sync status' logging, and append to sync logging table (sync page)
function GetSyncStatusUsers(selectFromGroup)
{
var currentArray;

$.post("php/getServerLogging.php",
{
    command: "GetLastSyncUser",
    groupName: selectFromGroup
})

.success(function (data)
{
    var jsonMessage = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#dataTables-example td').remove();
    $("#dataTables-example tr:empty").remove();

    // Check to see if response message returns back "OK"
    if (jsonMessage.RESPONSE == 'OK')
    {

        if ($("#dataTables-example").length)
        {

            var syncStatusTableBody = $('#dataTables-example').children('tbody');
            var syncStatusTable = syncStatusTableBody.length ? syncStatusTableBody : $('#dataTables-example');

            // Loop through all the returned records and add them to select box
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonMessage.RECORDS.length; i++)
            {

                var currentRecord = jsonMessage.RECORDS[i];

                // Returned from mysql timestamp/datetime field
                var LastSyncTime;
                if (currentRecord['LastSync'] == null)
                {
                    LastSyncTime = "No Last sync record found";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Return last sync time in UK format
                    LastSyncTime =   GetCurrentDateUKFormatFromSQL(currentRecord['LastSync']['date']);
                }

                // Append to sync status table
                syncStatusTable.append("<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord['Firstname'] + ' ' + currentRecord['Surname'] + "</td><td>" + LastSyncTime + " (" + TimeAgo(SubtractDates(currentRecord['LastSync']['date'])) + ")" + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

**The way i've done this is by removing the following lines:**

```
$('#dataTables-example td').remove();
$("#dataTables-example tr:empty").remove();
var syncStatusTableBody = $('#dataTables-example').children('tbody');
var syncStatusTable = syncStatusTableBody.length ? syncStatusTableBody : $('#dataTables-example');
// Append to sync status table
syncStatusTable.append("<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord['Firstname'] + ' ' + currentRecord['Surname'] + "</td><td>" + LastSyncTime + " (" + TimeAgo(SubtractDates(currentRecord['LastSync']['date'])) + ")" + "</td></tr>");
```

**Adding these following lines:**

```
var tableRecord = '';
// Append to sync status table
tableRecord += "<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord['Firstname'] + ' ' + currentRecord['Surname'] + "</td><td>" + LastSyncTime + " (" + TimeAgo(SubtractDates(currentRecord['LastSync']['date'])) + ")" + "</td></tr>";
$('#dataTables-example').find('tbody').html(tableRecord);
```

So to see the difference in code, check the Previous code to the Working code

**Working Code:**

```
// Get all sync status' logging, and append to sync logging table (sync page)
function GetSyncStatusUsers(selectFromGroup)
{
var currentArray;


$.post("php/getServerLogging.php",
{
    command: "GetLastSyncUser",
    groupName: selectFromGroup
})

.success(function (data)
{
    var jsonMessage = JSON.parse(data);

    // Check to see if response message returns back "OK"
    if (jsonMessage.RESPONSE == 'OK')
    {

        if ($("#dataTables-example").length)
        {

            var tableRecord = '';

            // Loop through all the returned records and add them to select box
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonMessage.RECORDS.length; i++)
            {

                var currentRecord = jsonMessage.RECORDS[i];

                // Returned from mysql timestamp/datetime field
                var LastSyncTime;
                if (currentRecord['LastSync'] == null)
                {
                    LastSyncTime = "No Last sync record found";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Return last sync time in UK format
                    LastSyncTime = GetCurrentDateUKFormatFromSQL(currentRecord['LastSync']['date']);
                }

                // Append to sync status table
                tableRecord += "<tr id=" + currentRecord["PatientID"] + "><td class='patientListNames'>" + currentRecord['Firstname'] + ' ' + currentRecord['Surname'] + "</td><td>" + LastSyncTime + " (" + TimeAgo(SubtractDates(currentRecord['LastSync']['date'])) + ")" + "</td></tr>";
            }

            $('#dataTables-example').find('tbody').html(tableRecord);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure client-side filter solution, try using the jQuery DataTables plugin:

https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I've used datatables before and I know that's a solution, but i'm trying to get away from using more plugins.